# Prove the set is an event

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Suppose the sample space is the real numbers and that every interval of the form(-infinity, b] for any real number b is an event. Show that $(-\infty, b)$ is an event.

We can use unions of the limit of $(-\infty, b-\frac1n)$ as $n$ approaches $\infty$ to prove that $(-\infty, b)$ is an event. But I am not sure how to prove its complement set, that is $[b, \infty)$ is also an event.

Answer (score 0):

A countable union of events is an event. $(1)$
If you know that $(\infty,b]$ is an event for all $b$, then since :
$$\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} (-\infty,b-\frac 1 n] =(-\infty,b),$$
$(-\infty,b)$ is an event.

The complementary of an event is also an event. $(2)$ 
Then $[b,\infty($ is an event.

Properties $(1)$ and $(2)$ follow from the definition of a probability space. Remember that the event space is a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: The statement that the complementary of an event is also an event is a condition that must be satisfied. Isn't it? or is that the complement of an event is always an event? how do i prove that [b, infinity) is an event?

Comment: The complementary of an event is always an event, by definition of an event space. Then if $(-\infty,b)$ is an event, $[b,\infty)=(-\infty,b)^c$ is one as well.